# Cast to the interface when using Socket in Java

Tags: java, sockets, serialization, interface

I got a really unfathomable problem. So I created two different projects and decided to test my socket applications which tries to send an interface over network. Here is my client side code:

```
package calculable;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class ClientToSendCalculable
{
    public ClientToSendCalculable(int port)
    {
        try
        (
            Socket s = new Socket("localhost", port);
            ObjectOutputStream writer = new ObjectOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
            ObjectInputStream reader = new ObjectInputStream(s.getInputStream());
        )
        {
            System.out.println("Connection was established!");

            Calculable addition = new Addition(5, 7);

            writer.writeObject(addition);
            double res = (Double)reader.readObject();

            System.out.println(res);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new ClientToSendCalculable(7777);
    }
}
```

Here is my server side code:

```
package calculable;

import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class ServerToGetCalculable
{
    public ServerToGetCalculable(int port)
    {
        while(true)
        {
            try
                    (
                            ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(port);
                            Socket s = ss.accept();
                            ObjectOutputStream writer = new ObjectOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
                            ObjectInputStream reader = new ObjectInputStream(s.getInputStream());
                    )
            {
                System.out.println("Got a client!");

                Calculable calcObj = (Calculable) reader.readObject();
                double res = calcObj.calc();
                writer.writeObject(res);
            }catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {new ServerToGetCalculable(7777);}
}
```

Here is interface Calculable:

```
package calculable;

import java.io.Serializable;

public interface Calculable extends Serializable
{
    double calc();
}
```

I have Calculable interface in both projects. But I have Addition class only in client side project. Here is Addition class:

```
package calculable;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class Addition implements Calculable, Serializable
{
    private double firstAddendum, secondAddendum;

    public Addition(double firstAddendum, double secondAddendum)
    {
        this.firstAddendum = firstAddendum;
        this.secondAddendum = secondAddendum;
    }

    public double calc()
    {
        return firstAddendum + secondAddendum;
    }
}
```

When I start server.main class first and client.main class after I got such exceptions:

exception on the server side:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\bin\java" -Didea.launcher.port=7544 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3.3\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program .....E:\Cloud\JavaIdea\ForCalculablePractice\out\production\ForCalculablePractice;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3.3\lib\idea_rt.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain calculable.ServerToGetCalculable
Got a client!
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: calculable.Addition
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.resolveClass(ObjectInputStream.java:628)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1620)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1521)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1781)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:373)
    at calculable.ServerToGetCalculable.<init>(ServerToGetCalculable.java:24)
    at calculable.ServerToGetCalculable.main(ServerToGetCalculable.java:36)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

exception on the client side:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\bin\java" -Didea.launcher.port=7545 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3.3\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\jre\lib\charsets.jar;.....E:\Cloud\JavaIdea\SocketPractice\out\production\SocketPractice;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3.3\lib\idea_rt.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain calculable.ClientToSendCalculable
Connection was established!
java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.peekByte(ObjectInputStream.java:2626)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1321)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:373)
    at calculable.ClientToSendCalculable.<init>(ClientToSendCalculable.java:22)
    at calculable.ClientToSendCalculable.main(ClientToSendCalculable.java:34)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do **not** send interfaces - that is a misconception on your end. The fact that you put down:

```
Calculable addition = new Addition(5, 7);
```

doesn't mean that you put an "interface" object on the wire.

You send a **serialized** object. That objects contains a **hard** link to its **specific** class. See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/serialization/spec/protocol.html) for more details.

You can't fix this **in code**. You have to make sure that the **class* of your serialized object is available to the JVM where you intend to de-serialize. It is that simple.

Comment: Can you provide me with an appropriate code changes that I have to do in order for my program to work with server and client being in different projects, please?

Comment: @Yaroslav Just copy your addition class.

Comment: @GhostCat, I just upvoted. Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You're sending an object that the server has no knowledge of.  You need add the class files for for the `additions` object, including `Addition` and `Calculable` to the server's classpath (or your project if using an IDE).